# How to get OID of a BSON object as a hex string?

Tags: c++, mongodb, serialization, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

I am using the `mongo-cxx` driver trying to convert the object ID of a `BSON` object to a string

```
BSONObj r=some_function();
BSONElement oi;
r.getObjectID(oi);
OID o=oi.__oid();
cout<<"oid:"<<o.toString()<<endl;`
```

I am sure that the `BSONObj` has valid data but I get the following error:

> BSONElement: bad type #somenumber

Comment: Check that the object's ID is actually of OID type. Or use a checked OID() call instead of __oid().

Comment: still getting the same error. Am i using the function getObjectID correctly? The API documentation doesn't explain enough on it.

Comment: Try this: std::string oid = r["_id"].OID().toString();

Comment: It still didn't work. The function OID() isn't defined in the BSONElement class .

Comment: I figured out my mistake and have added an answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The query object returns a pointer to the buffer where the `BSONObj` is stored.
I went wrong when I did not use the function `BSONObj::getOwned()` to request a copy of the `BSONObj` which was causing the exception.